# Solr-Atomic Update changes other fields

Tags: solr

While running on atomic update,language field is getting changed.We have flow as below.

During indexing object posted is
{
id:"234-567",
fileName:"file1",
content:""
}

In the pipeline we analyse content as part of language detection and create a new field "language" which is working as expected.

But while doing atomic update 
{
id:"as above"
fileName:"changed"
}

to change fileName,we make use to "set" operation which is updating field correctly but **language** field is getting changed to fallback value.

What is happening here?Is it looking for content field to analysis again?Does atomic update also goes through processing pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the language detection is run again, and there is no value available for that field for the language detection to actually detect anything for.

Run updates without language detection unless you're including the field you're running language detection on.

You might have to define a second request handler without the language detection settings if you have those defined as static settings in your request handler configuration.

Comment: Thanks.I have resorted to keeping language detection outside solr itself.